# creating columns in a database table using talend context variables

Tags: mysql, database, talend

I am trying to generate columns in myql database using context variables in talend open studio. 
 How can we generate context query accordingly to that. I have searched in google, there are some answers using tfileInput and then edit schema so you can add columns manually there, but I don't want to follow this oder. I am having tMysqlRow as input connected to my local DB and under query section of that how can I use context variables to generate columns in database. In this way I don't need to drop the table when I have to add a new column.

Comment: Talend is primarily an ETL tool.  Creating tables is a byproduct of loading data.  My advice is to ask a better question.  But if you really want to do it with a context variable, then create your variable and enter an alter statement then "select 1"  In MS SQL separate with a semicolon.   Then in a SQLInput object, in the query section reference your context variable.  SQLInput object requires a result set, therefore the select 1.
I have tested it and it works, but I really see no purpose to doing it way and think you should reevaluate how you are using the tool.

Comment: @ELaRoche probably you didn't understood the question exactly, I wanted to create a class body by using context variables in talend so that instead of creating sql tables manually I would just give my details in a file and when ever I run the job a table is created in workbench. Nevertheless I have solved it. Thanks

Comment: How do you accept new columns? As far as I know you'd have to alter the job every time a column changes.

Comment: @tobi6 I don't want to change a column once if I have a fixed table. I would create a subjob which is modular and reusable. For instance it acts like a class and creates as many objects needed. Once you have a modular job all you need to do is give the column names there and it creates a new table but not altering the old table.

Comment: I am very interested how you would provide dynamic column names for a modular job. As far as I know, Talend is not that flexible without custom Java.